# Failing to make array of multiple items in php with same item name

Tags: php, arrays

```
 $categoryArray=array();
 $dataseries1=array();
 $dataseries2=array();
 // pushing category array values
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
 $lundra1 = $row['lundra'];
 $ghargoda1 = $row['ghargoda'];
 $shankargadh1 = $row['shankargarh'];
 $pratappur1 = $row['pratappur'];
 $charma1 = $row['charama'];
 $bharatpur1 = $row['bharatpur'];
 $carmdaksh1 = $row['carmdaksh'];
 $pali1 = $row['pali'];
 $magarload1 = $row['magarload'];
 $bodla1 = $row['bodla'];
 $chhindgarh1 = $row['chhindgarh'];
 $dantewada1 = $row['dantewada'];
 $bakawand1 = $row['bakawand'];
 $narharpur1 = $row['narharpur'];
 $total1 = $row['total'];    
 array_push($categoryArray, array(
          "label" => "Lundra",
          "label" => "Ghargoda",
          "label" => "Shankargarh",
          "label" => "Pratappur",
          "label" => "Charama"
          )
        );
```

This is giving output as

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => Charama ) )
```

And what m trying to do is like this

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => Jan ) [1] => Array ( [label] => Feb ) [2] => Array ( [label] => Mar ) [3] => Array ( [label] => Apr ) [4] => Array ( [label] => May ) [5] => Array ( [label] => Jun ))
```

M new with using arrays so facing problem on how to bring this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 array_push($categoryArray, array(
          "label" => "Lundra"
          ),array(
          "label" => "Ghargoda"
          ),array(
          "label" => "Shankargarh"
          ),array(
          "label" => "Pratappur"
          ),array(
          "label" => "Charama"
          )
        );
```

This will provide you with your required output

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you are facing is that an array is build with keys.

E.g. Numeric

```
1 => First,
2 => Second,
...
```

E.g. with names

```
first_entry => First,
second_entry => Second,
...
```

When you define multiple entries in an array they overwrite each other.
To fix that you have to define an array in the main array for each item.

```
 array_push($categoryArray, array(
      array("label" => "Lundra"),
      array("label" => "Ghargoda"),
      array("label" => "Shankargarh"),
      array("label" => "Pratappur"),
      array("label" => "Charama)"
      )
    );
```

That way the result would be like  `Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => Jan ) [1] => Array ( [label] => Feb ) [2] => Array ( [label] => Mar ) [3] => Array ( [label] => Apr ) [4] => Array ( [label] => May ) [5] => Array ( [label] => Jun ))`.